# KDE desktop without dolphin file manager

Tags: 12.04, kde

It is possible to install KDE4 with plasma and effects, but without default applications like Dolphin? I already have XFCE with all useful applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It seems it is possible to have KDE experience without basic KDE apps. You have to install `plasma-desktop` package. But this will be too basic KDE to experience anything, and also note `thunar` or `nautilus` won't integrate good with KDE.

To install plasma-desktop:

- Open a terminal and use the command `sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop`

  or using Software Center [image: Install via the software center]

To install a good but minimal KDE experience, I suggest installing `kde-plasma-desktop` package. It includes basic KDE workspace with file managers, text editors, terminal emulator  etc.